# C# Variable Scope Question, and Text-based RPG Attempt

Tags: c#, scope

I am trying to write a text-based RPG in C#. I am having issues understanding how I could make the character data accessible to many other objects in an effective manner.

I am fairly new to programming, and I certainly lack information. I've been reading guides and questions online and it got me so far, but I feel like I am either thinking about this the wrong way or missing something completely.

I am trying to write everything as flexible as possible since I am planning on adding a lot to this project if I can get past this stage. But it seems difficult for me to allow all of these objects to actively communicate with each other. Would using Unity help with this? I am mostly doing this to learn the language so I can later use it w/ Unity, but I wanted to learn the language directly so I opted out of starting with Unity. If there are any suggested resources to learn about the language I could really use recommendations.

I am sorry if the question is too open ended, but I can't really find anything regarding the mindset behind how I should be building a system like this. The last thing I've learned is ref but I feel like that isn't the best answer.

```
namespace GameMain
{
public class Game
{

    static void Main()
    {
        MainMenu Game = new MainMenu();
        Game.Menu();
        return;
    }

}
public class MainMenu
{
    Character CurrentPlayer = new Character();
    public void Menu()
    {
        Music MusicPlayer = new Music();
        LocationEngine Location = new LocationEngine();
        Tester Testman = new Tester();
        MusicPlayer.Track("0");
        while (true)
        {
        Menu:
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the main menu. Enter 'create' to create a character and begin the game. Enter 'play' to log in.\r\nSaving features are to be implemented.\r\n");
            while (true)
            {
                string MenuSelection = Console.ReadLine();
                if (MenuSelection == "create")
                {
                    CurrentPlayer.Creation();
                    goto Menu;
                }
                else if (MenuSelection == "play")
                {
                    if (CurrentPlayer.CharacterPass != "")
                    {
                        Console.Write("\r\nEnter your password: ");
                        string Password = Console.ReadLine();
                        bool Check = CurrentPlayer.Login(Password);
                        if (Check == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\r\nAdd transition to location here.");
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please create a character first.\r\n");
                        break;

                    }

                }
            }
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress any key to continue.\r\n");
                Console.ReadKey();
                string TownSelection = "";
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nYou are in Town.\r\n\r\nYou can 'explore' for encounters\r\nYou can use 'stats' to check your character\r\nOr you can 'sleep' to return to the main menu\r\n");
                TownSelection = Console.ReadLine();
                if (TownSelection == "sleep")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    break;
                }
                else if (TownSelection == "stats")
                {
                    CurrentPlayer.CharacterStats();
                }
            }







        }
    }
}
}
```

I don't know how I can make the CurrentPlayer object accessible to the other objects such as Location. Is it better to pass every relevant bit as reference all the way down the rabbit hole?

I have posted the entire thing on github here if you are feeling extra patient: https://github.com/Slocknog/rpgproject

...and thank you for the help. Please do comment on anything else that you think I should be doing differently or reading up on.

Comment: You have a database of players/characters.  A database is normally a static object s I would make a static class that contains all you database objects and put into a static class.

Comment: you could have all those _"other objects"_ Constructors accept a `Character` object to which you'll provide `CurrentPlayer`

Comment: @jdweng: "A database is normally a static object s" - I would definitely disagree with that. As soon as you have global state like that, testing is much harder. I would far prefer using dependency injection for that sort of thing. Even if the OP isn't learning about testing yet, I would avoid getting into bad habits of relying on global state.

Comment: One aside - it would be worth learning about more abut naming conventions within C#. Typically local variables use `camelCase` instead of `PascalCase`. I'd also try to refactor your code to avoid `goto` statements - they're very rare within idiomatic handwritten code. Likewise classes are normally located in files with the same name, e.g. `LocationEngine.cs` instead of `locations.cs`. And you'd *probably* want all of this code within the same namespace, instead of each file using a different namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a step back and make sure you understand the purpose of each class you write. (This may sound patronizing, but it's really not trying to be. This is a difficult part of design.)

The purpose of each class should be clear and constrained: it should be reasonably obvious whether any piece of functionality belongs in a particular class or not, and no class should take on too much responsibility. I'd encourage you to write documentation comments on each class to explain its purpose - this will make it easier for you to come back and ask yourself whether some aspect of state and functionality really makes sense for that class.

Next, think about three ways data can be available to the class:

- Through static variables. This is effectively global state, and is best restricted to natural constants. Global state should usually be immutable (unless it's something like a cache) as otherwise it can make testing and reasoning about your code fairly difficult.
- Through instance variables. This is the state for an instance of the class (an object). It should be state that feels like it naturally belongs to an instance for its whole lifetime.
- Through method parameters. This is information that is useful just for the duration of a single method call. For example, I don't think a `LocationEngine` should really know about the `Character` as part of global or instance state, but it *might* make sense to pass a `Character` reference into a method. (It might make more sense to pass a `Location` reference into the method, which might be obtained from a `Character` - it's hard to say without effectively trying to do a large portion of design for you.)

It's definitely worth putting significant thought into these decisions early on - although you should still expect to make mistakes. If you find yourself having to write code that feels ugly quite a lot of the time, in terms of how it accesses information, think about whether that information currently "lives" in the right place.

(Oh, and you're wise to separate "learning C#" from "learning Unity" in my view. Quite a lot of Unity uses idioms/techniques/conventions that would raise eyebrows in other C# codebases. Learning about them only when you move into Unity means you're less likely to carry them over to writing C# code elsewhere. Additionally, debugging "regular" C# code, particularly console applications, is somewhat simpler than having to worry about the Unity editor etc.)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I was writing down ideas and ways to implement mechanics far beyond my reach. I will be taking that step back and really put some thought into the classes. I have this habit of using classes like disposable functions, which gets my code tangled up into a big mess. Listing the ways that data is available to a class was surprisingly helpful too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you could have all those "other objects" Constructors accept a `Character` object to which you'll provide `CurrentPlayer`

supposing you have the following `Character` class

```
class Character
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then your `LocationEngine` class would be:

```
class LocationEngine
{
    Character _player;
    public LocationEngine(Character player)
    {
        _player = player;
    }

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
       string playerName = _player.Name;
   }
}
```

and in your MainMenu class you'd code:

```
public class MainMenu
{
    Character CurrentPlayer = new Character();

    LocationEngine location = new LocationEngine(CurrentPlayer);

    ...
}
```

Comment: I will definitely be using this to better pass information between my objects. Thank you!

Comment: I do agree that Location only needs to know the location, which could be passed alone. The reason I wrote the whole thing like that is mostly because I needed to test things and the LocationEngine was the most convenient thing to try it on. I will most likely be passing the whole character over for combat.

Comment: @Slocknog, BTW, what way are you going on with: passing `Character` instances in some other object constructor or what?